# How to infer the type from the default value of a function?

Tags: typescript

I would like to be able to infer the return value type from the default value of the function, and would appreciate ideas or help.

link: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAEwJYngXjgb2HOBrARgC4sdd8B9EACyQBsELi4CAaMgX3dzwCYTs5SjXqN+cXtzgdgM4DACeABwCmcAJIARFOjiLVYAGaIdwYIYCuEVEkhwA5ipgAZADwAFOCoAeMFRAQofBUFIw1tVAA+AAp9FRJPDAByQiSASlJcACcnCyyIE1QAbTiAXVkzcGh4OgI4DEcXaLTgWoA6PCpaBiZKyFg4Ojp6hydnaJTedNa6Dq7RCl5gIA)

```js
const dict = {
  k1: {
    k_child_1: 1,
  },
  k2: {
    k_child_2: 2,
  }
}

type IDict = typeof dict

function getL<P extends keyof IDict>(type: P = 'k1') {  // <---- default value
  return dict[type]
}

const l1 = getL()
l1.k_child_1   //  <--- Hopefully, it can be infer that k1

const ll = getL('k2')
ll.k_child_2
```

Comment: Translating the solution from the other question here gives [this](https://tsplay.dev/nmqzdW).

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I did not notice your comment

Answer (score 2):

Here is working example:

```js
const dict = {
  k1: {
    k_child_1: 1,
  },
  k2: {
    k_child_2: 2,
  }
}

type IDict = typeof dict

function getL<P extends keyof IDict>(type: P): IDict[P]
function getL(): IDict['k1']
function getL(type: keyof IDict = 'k1') {
  return dict[type]
}

const l1 = getL()
l1.k_child_1

const ll = getL('k2')
ll.k_child_2

const ll2 = getL('k1')
ll2.k_child_1
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAEwJYngXjgb2HOBrARgC4sdd8B9EACyQBsELi4CAaMgX3dzwCYTs5SjXqN%20cXtzgdgM4DACeABwCmcAJIARFOjiLVYAGaIdwYIYCuEVEkhwA5ipgAZADwAFOCoAeMFRAQofBUFIw1tVAA%20AAp9FRJ3AEoSLR0AbXcAXXMrGztHF2jk8PSAckJS7MtrGFsIBydnWOV44NDjVNQ4DHKCUsTSXAAnJwsh%20uRUNLjsuXBoeDoCbobCxOAlgDo8KloGJjN52Dg6OhWCpvLefo26bd3RCl5DyGPT3nPG6N6b9-uRfYEIA)

In your particular case, useing `extends` is much useful in overloadings than in main declaration.